# How to pick users systems date time format and parse it in db like dd/mm/yyyy in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, validation, datetime, user-controls, calendar

I have an issue if user selects date time format German or any other my code is not working it sucks on Try Parse Exact.

```
 else if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(tbAgentsAgentComparisonByQuestionaireFrom.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out tempDate))
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Invalid start date";
                ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).SetFocus(tbAgentsAgentComparisonByQuestionaireFrom);
                isvalid = false;
            }
            else if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(tbAgentsAgentComparisonByQuestionaireTo.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out tempDate))
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Invalid end date";
                ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).SetFocus(tbAgentsAgentComparisonByQuestionaireTo);
                isvalid = false;
            }
```

And asp.net control is like

```
 <td style="padding-top: 5px; *padding-top: 3px; padding-left: 2px;">
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="tbAgentsAgentComparisonByQuestionaireTo" runat="server" CssClass="textBoxStyle"
                                            meta:resourcekey="tbAgentsAgentComparisonByQuestionaireToResource1" 
                                            Width="282px"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgDateCampaignEnd" runat="server" CssClass="imgbutton" ImageUrl="~/Images/Calendar.png"
                                            meta:resourcekey="imgDateCampaignEndResource1" />
                                        <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="calAgentsAgentComparisonByQuestionaireTo" runat="server"
                                            Enabled="True" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" PopupButtonID="imgDateCampaignEnd" TargetControlID="tbAgentsAgentComparisonByQuestionaireTo">
                                        </cc1:CalendarExtender>
                                    </td>
```

How can i use the technique in web.config. I want if user changes his machine date time format to any other region like german or any other than how it should work. Thanks in advance :)

Exception which comes is

```
 2-1-2014 | 15:18:30:698 | Exception
--------
MESSAGE
--------
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
--------
STACK TRACE
--------
   at System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String format, IFormatProvider provider)
   at QualityMonitor.CampaignSummary.ValidateForm()
2-1-2014 | 15:18:30:699 | Exception
```

Comment: @zgood would you please suggest me the solution .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` in place of CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.

Like this

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(tbAgentsAgentComparisonByQuestionaireFrom.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out tempDate)
```